# When is laravel executing the yearly() function

Tags: laravel, scheduling, laravel-scheduler

When is laravel executing the yearly() function of it's task scheduling? Is it from the first time it was used or is it each year on 01.01.YYYY?

I checked up the laravel docs and several pages, but I wasn't able to find out the answer to this question.

```
$schedule->call(function () {
  DB::table("invoice_settings")
    ->where("key", "invoice_number")
    ->update(["value" => 860001]);
  })->yearly();
```

I expect that it's running on the 01.01.YYYY.

Comment: it's indeed yearly starting 01.01.YYYY

Answer (score 5):

Laravel's yearly coresponds to crontab's yearly event. Described here:

https://crontab.guru/every-year

Answer (score 4):

This is the cron produced:

```
0 0 1 1 *
```

Which runs:

> At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 in January.

Answer (score 3):

The yearly function is defined in:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/ManagesFrequencies.php
```

Here you can find the daily, monthly and yearly, and other frequency functions.

```
public function daily()
{
    return $this->spliceIntoPosition(1, 0)
                ->spliceIntoPosition(2, 0);
}

public function monthly()
{
    return $this->spliceIntoPosition(1, 0)
                ->spliceIntoPosition(2, 0)
                ->spliceIntoPosition(3, 1);
}

public function yearly()
{
    return $this->spliceIntoPosition(1, 0)
                ->spliceIntoPosition(2, 0)
                ->spliceIntoPosition(3, 1)
                ->spliceIntoPosition(4, 1);
}
```

As in the official Laravel documentation is written that the daily function runs daily at midnight, since the yearly function is defined in the same way it will run at the 1/1/YYYY at midnight.